# Bootstrap number validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having Bootstrap and I have problem with validation. I need input only positive integer. 
How to implement it?

For example:

```
<div>                       
    <input type="number" id="replyNumber" data-bind="value:replyNumber" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 59):

It's not Twitter bootstrap specific, it is a normal HTML5 component and you can specify the range with the `min` and `max` attributes (in your case only the first attribute). For example:

```html
<div>                       
    <input type="number" id="replyNumber" min="0" data-bind="value:replyNumber" />
</div>
```

I'm not sure if only integers are allowed by default in the control or not, but else you can specify the `step` attribute:

```html
<div>                       
    <input type="number" id="replyNumber" min="0" step="1" data-bind="value:replyNumber" />
</div>
```

Now only numbers higher (and equal to) zero can be used and there is a step of 1, which means the values are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... .

**BE AWARE**: Not all browsers support the HTML5 features, so it's recommended to have some kind of JavaScript fallback (and in your back-end too) if you really want to use the constraints.

For a list of browsers that support it, you can look at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number).

Comment: How implement JavaScript fallback?

Comment: The JavaScript fallback should add an onChange event handler to your input field and validate the number (try parsing it to an integer first and then check if it's above zero).

Comment: I can still input characters.

Comment: @jned29 what browser do you use? Firefox does allow character input, but marks the field as invalid when you do. Chrome/Opera do not allow character input. In IE it should also work. Safari still has issues, true that: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation. That's why I said you need a proper fallback if you have to support incompatible browsers.

Answer (score 17):

Well I always use the same easy way and it works for me.
In your HTML keep the type as text (like this):

```
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="onlyNumbers" name="onlyNumbers" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onpaste="return false;"/>
```

After this you only need to add a method on javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if ( (charCode > 31 && charCode < 48) || charCode > 57) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

With this easy validation you will only get positive numbers as you wanted.
You can modify the charCodes to add more valid keys to your method.

Here´s the code working: [Only numbers validation](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm2hS/)

Comment: fails at copy&paste

Comment: was just about to mention the same that fails at copy-paste. How to prevent this and at the same time ensure numeric input only?

Comment: @SuhaibAhmad you can try by adding this into the button onpaste="return false;"
If this solve the problem let me know to edit the solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @fubo you can try by adding this into the button onpaste="return false;"
If this solve the problem let me know to edit the solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: it will fail on drag and drop too

Comment: what if I need to input float values upto 2 decimal points? e.g. 100.99

Answer (score 2):

You should use jquery validation because if you use `type="number"` then you can also enter "E" character in input type, which is not correct.

**Solution:**

HTML

```
<input class="form-control floatNumber" name="energy1_total_power_generated" type="text" required="" >
```

JQuery

```
//integer value validation
$('input.floatNumber').on('input', function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use PATTERN:

```
<input class="form-control" minlength="1" pattern="[0-9]*" [(ngModel)]="value" #name="ngModel">

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="text-danger">
  <div *ngIf="name.errors?.pattern">Is not a number</div>
</div>
```